# trying to install linux headers but not found in sources

Tags: apt, arm, linux-headers

I have a ts7400v2 sbc and I am trying to install the linux-headers. I run:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

but get the following error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ts7400-4e7b7c
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-2.6.35.3-571-gcca29a0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-2.6.35.3-571-gcca29a0'
```

is there a particular source I am missing?

EDIT:

output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux ts7400-4e7b7c 2.6.35.3-571-gcca29a0+ #2 PREEMPT Mon Mar 16 14:56:01 PDT 2015 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

output for `apt-cache search linux-headers`

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all-armel - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.2.0-4
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-iop32x - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-iop32x
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-ixp4xx - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-ixp4xx
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-kirkwood - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-kirkwood
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-mv78xx0 - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-mv78xx0
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-orion5x - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-orion5x
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-versatile - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-versatile
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-all - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-all-armel - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-common - Common header files for Linux 3.2.0-5
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-iop32x - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-5-iop32x
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-ixp4xx - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-5-ixp4xx
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-kirkwood - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-5-kirkwood
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-mv78xx0 - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-5-mv78xx0
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-orion5x - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-5-orion5x
linux-headers-3.2.0-5-versatile - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-5-versatile
linux-headers-2.6-iop32x - Header files for Linux iop32x configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-ixp4xx - Header files for Linux ixp4xx configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-kirkwood - Header files for Linux kirkwood configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-orion5x - Header files for Linux orion5x configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-versatile - Header files for Linux versatile configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-iop32x - Header files for Linux iop32x configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-ixp4xx - Header files for Linux ixp4xx configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-kirkwood - Header files for Linux kirkwood configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-mv78xx0 - Header files for Linux mv78xx0 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-orion5x - Header files for Linux orion5x configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-versatile - Header files for Linux versatile configuration (meta-package)
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please add the output of `uname -a` and `apt-cache search linux-headers` , [you cane edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/434666/edit)

Comment: Run `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` reboot then use the first command in your question to install the `linux-headers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TS4700 v2 SBC isn’t supported by the standard Debian kernel, it uses a variant provided by the manufacturer. This means you can’t use Debian-provided kernel packages, including the header packages.

To build extra modules for the system, you should cross-compile, building the kernel on the SBC isn’t recommended. See [the TS wiki](https://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/TS-7400-V2#Compile_the_Kernel) for details; basically you’ll need to clone the appropriate repository and use that to build:

```
git clone https://github.com/embeddedarm/linux-2.6.35.3-imx28.git
```